# Android c2dm how to work with turkish(all languages) characters?

Tags: android, encoding, character, android-c2dm

i am developing a c2dm server side application and  my code like this;

```
string postData = GetPostStringFrom(postFieldNameValue);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "GoogleLogin auth=" + authTokenString);

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
```

and my android side code which i handle it;

```
String message = intent.getExtras().getString( "message" );
```

i handle this successfully but text was missing.

for example:

i send "türkçe öçşğıü" but i can handle only "trke"

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolve this problem.

we need to uri encoding for my sending data. when i was encode data, i can sent it.

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

try sending char type as unicode in
.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";